# Xcode no longer compile after my friend upgrade his iPhone to 6.1

Tags: xcode4.5

No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

I can still compile on my iPhone but not on my friends' iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Xcode 4.6 for iOS 6.1 devices

Answer (score 2):

ya you need Xcode 4.6 ..check the link for more...

[Xcode 4.6 released alongside iOS 6.1](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/01/28/xcode-4-6-released-alongside-ios-6-1/)