# run the app on iPhone 3GS os 6.1 using Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

I am using Xcode 4.3.2 and want to run app on iPhone 3GS but when I am opening organizer window and showing  following:

The version of iOS on “iPhone” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on iPhone
6.1 (10B141)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
5.1 (9B176)
5.0
4.3
4.2

please suggest me .

Comment: Use your iPhone 3Gs udid in your development provisioning portal....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743016/xcode-no-longer-compile-after-my-friend-upgrade-his-iphone-to-6-1/14743067#14743067 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743016/xcode-no-longer-compile-after-my-friend-upgrade-his-iphone-to-6-1/14743031#14743031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since downgrading the iOS version is difficult and doesn’t sound like an option for you, I think you must follow the other option:

> update to the latest version of the iOS SDK

The iOS 6.1 SDK is included in [Xcode 4.6](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12).

Answer (score 0):

Make your code compatible for ios 6.1
and try using xcode 4.5

Comment: 6.1 is not compatible with 4.5, you need to upgrade it to 4.6.